# Bind authentication with Oracle in CAS

Tags: cas

I'm setting up CAS 5.3 to do Bind authentication agains an Oracle database. But I don't know how to setup a OracleDataSource while using WAR Overlay method. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Just setting up Driver and URL doesn't appear to work. It seems the HikariDataSource is used by default, and it doesn't implement the required getConnection(String username, String password).

```
@SneakyThrows
public static DataSource newDataSource(final AbstractJpaProperties jpaProperties) {
    final String dataSourceName = jpaProperties.getDataSourceName();
    final boolean proxyDataSource = jpaProperties.isDataSourceProxy();

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(dataSourceName)) {
        try {
            final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            dsLookup.setResourceRef(false);
            final DataSource containerDataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource(dataSourceName);
            if (!proxyDataSource) {
                return containerDataSource;
            }
            return new DataSourceProxy(containerDataSource);
        } catch (final DataSourceLookupFailureException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Lookup of datasource [{}] failed due to {} falling back to configuration via JPA properties.", dataSourceName, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    final HikariDataSource bean = new HikariDataSource();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jpaProperties.getDriverClass())) {
        bean.setDriverClassName(jpaProperties.getDriverClass());
    }
    bean.setJdbcUrl(jpaProperties.getUrl());
    bean.setUsername(jpaProperties.getUser());
    bean.setPassword(jpaProperties.getPassword());
    bean.setLoginTimeout((int) Beans.newDuration(jpaProperties.getPool().getMaxWait()).getSeconds());
    bean.setMaximumPoolSize(jpaProperties.getPool().getMaxSize());
    bean.setMinimumIdle(jpaProperties.getPool().getMinSize());
    bean.setIdleTimeout((int) Beans.newDuration(jpaProperties.getIdleTimeout()).toMillis());
    bean.setLeakDetectionThreshold(jpaProperties.getLeakThreshold());
    bean.setInitializationFailTimeout(jpaProperties.getFailFastTimeout());
    bean.setIsolateInternalQueries(jpaProperties.isIsolateInternalQueries());
    bean.setConnectionTestQuery(jpaProperties.getHealthQuery());
    bean.setAllowPoolSuspension(jpaProperties.getPool().isSuspension());
    bean.setAutoCommit(jpaProperties.isAutocommit());
    bean.setValidationTimeout(jpaProperties.getPool().getTimeoutMillis());
    return bean;
}
```

I would require that the bean created above, would be a OracleDataSource instance.

Comment: Would like to know, did you try to use the default configuration given by CAS instead of building your own database configuration? Some link for reference: https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#database-authentication, https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/JDBC-Drivers.html

Comment: Yeah, I can authenticate using the default "search" JDBC method, my problem lies when I try to use "bind" method.

Comment: Oic, I am not familiar with Oracle DB so can't help you further, sorry about that.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to make use of another datasource? Instead of the default Hikari?

Comment: No, I just use Hikari in my CAS server

Comment: I find it weird that the default CAS bind authentication handler doesn't work with Hikari... Perhaps a bug?

Comment: The only way I can think of it to work would be to define a container datasource using JNDI... didn't want to though...

Comment: Actually, there might be a better change of people giving your answer in the CAS google group https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!forum/cas-user. The CAS community is not very active in Stackoverflow.